# "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150004). Click OK to close the application."

Tags: windows-7

I get this error whenever I try to start World of Warcraft, Audacity, or Blender. What does it mean, and how can I fix it? This is on Windows 7 64-bit.

This was all I could find in the event log:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20042439/error2.png]

It looks like all it logged was the appearance of the dialog box.

Comment: Has the computer always done this, or is this new?  Have you tried a System Restore back to a point when it DID work? Aynthing in the Event logs?

Comment: It's done it long enough that a restore really isn't an option. Not sure where the logs are.

Comment: How-to [Open Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-event-viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is often caused by a faulty set of older (2005) C++ libraries.

Try removing and reinstalling them.

You can get an updated version from MS here: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=14431) (or the original 64-bit version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=21254)).

***Edit:***

I'm still pretty sure this is a Visual C++ runtime library problem.  Perhaps it's not the 2005 version specifically in this case.

Check your Add/Remove Programs and determine which, if any, MS VC++ runtime libraries you have installed.  And, as before, uninstall and reinstall them.

Here's some links to help you get them:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=2092)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632)
- [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Comment: That didn't seem to help, unfortunately.

Comment: See my edit. :)

Comment: OK, I uninstalled all the other versions I had & installed the ones you linked to--and it seems to work now. Thank you so much! I've been searching for a solution to this problem forever.

Comment: Glad it worked. :)