# "Apple Program Errors: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150004). Click OK to close the application."

Tags: windows-7, runtime-error, runtime

I did refer to this: ["The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150004). Click OK to close the application."](https://superuser.com/questions/559869/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0150004-click-ok-to-close-t). I looked up my runtime ribraries and found out I had two 2005, two 2008, and two 2010 runtime libraries. I did what techie007 said to do and uninstalled all my runtime libraries and used his links to reinstall them. I only ended up with 4 libraries, however, because only the 2005 library link had the two versions I had, the 2008 and 2010 links only had one version. The programs (QuickTimePlayer.exe and APSDaemon.exe) still didn't work and displayed the same error.

Questions about runtime libraries: Do I need replaced versions of the runtime libraries I have or do I just need the latest library?-Other sources seem to contradict the replacing and say to get the latest library.

This is also on a windows 7 64-bit. What do I do to get these programs running?

Comment: 0xc0150004 = STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND. Do this: http://pastebin.com/ZbfMC41R

Comment: @magicandre1981 I did exactly what was said in the pastebin, the text file is blank. Tried it 3 times.

Comment: ok, use depends.exe and trace it there: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx Does this show you which DLL is missing?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Oh my god...where exactly is the download link? Went from your link to the link on your link and I downloaded one of the downloads. All it did was unzip some things into a temp file, which I can't delete now because some part of it is open.

Comment: the latest version is part of the Win8.1 SDK/WDK. I've uploaded it here for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8k78vll2cga7q4/depends_x64.zip

Comment: @magicandre1981 Two things from the other thing I downloaded can't be deleted it says one is open is adobe reader and acrobat manager and the other is open in windows explorer. I don't think either of these are actually open. How do I delete these????

Comment: @magicandre1981 I used the second link you gave me there and quite a lot of .DLL's gave an error like this: Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).

Comment: post pictures of all errors

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry for taking so long, here http://imgur.com/8TRyUz0

Comment: looks like this is a 32Bit application. So you need the 32Bit Depends.exe: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqurq1yb4exnq0l/depends_x86.7z

Comment: @magicandre1981 here's a picture of all the errors with the new download: http://imgur.com/Gn8r67A

Comment: this doesn't look like you did the tracing.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I thought just dragging the file into the depends.exe was the tracing? What else do I do?

Comment: no, you must press F7 in the application. This is explained in the link I posted.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Still here. Sorry for taking so long with your instructions, I'll be faster from now on. http://imgur.com/DAhol56

Answer (score 0):

ok, the VC++ Runtime 8.0.50727.6195 is missing in the 32Bit Version. Download this C++ Runtime (vcredist_x86.EXE) and the issue should be fixed:

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347)

Comment: Problem installing the runtime library. I click run on the installer and go through and when it gets to the loading installing part it just exits out. I have tried it multiple times and as administrator. Also tried restarting my comp and re-downloading the installer. Got anything on this?

Comment: Run ProcMon in background and look for errors: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor

Comment: I believe the problem is : BUFFER TOO SMALL

Comment: no. Save the ProcMon log, zip and upload it.

Comment: Well...microsoft.exe didn't appear in the process names when I did it but here you go anyway https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilvs2h0bxhre4ym/Logfile.zip

Comment: you can access denied error in this key: **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\wextract_cleanup0**. Make sure no AV suite blocks this key.

Comment: What am I supposed to do with that again?

Comment: stop your AV suite or add this registry location to the exclude list inside the AV tool settings.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5dsftfjiq6dfvm/Logfile.zip

Comment: you still have the same ACCESS DENIED issue at the same registry key.

Comment: So how do I make sure no AV suite blocks that key?

Comment: remove Kaspersky completely and try to install the Runtime.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: do you still have the ACCESS DENIED error? Look into the log and filter for ACCESS DENIED errors.

Comment: What's the full filter line? There are 3 spots to fill in for the filter.

Comment: Filter for the RESULT column. Watch those 2 videos: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor and http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: Sorry for another long wait, hope you're still willing to help me out https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilvs2h0bxhre4ym/Logfile.zip

Comment: still the same. Access to reg key **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\wextract_cleanup0** is denied. Stopp all 3rd party tools (Clean boot) and try again.

Comment: I tried using the installer with the clean boot, it didn't work.

Comment: Could this help? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970652

Comment: I tried uninstalling all the other 2005 runtime libraries then running the installer you linked to. It installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributal version 8.0.61001, WHICH I ALREADY HAD. What do we do?

Comment: I have no idea. repair your Windows with the old InPlace upgrade: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: Nope, got confused at every turn, I literally can't even try.

Comment: what confuses you?

Comment: How do I know if I used to have or have Service Pack 1, and what is an ISO. To continue to do anything at all, what are they telling me to maybe download, and why, even if you go onto the download site there are like 200 different download links, can't do anything because I don't know about these things.

Comment: Run winver.exe to see if you use the Sp1. You can get the ISO from here: http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links

Comment: Alright, I do/did have SP1. Which ISO should I get exactly? There a lot of options under the English category. Also, is the production key they talk about the one that is under your computer? I don't want to get that far just to get stuck. Also-also, this process should not delete any of the programs I have, correct?

Comment: use the (media refresh) which fit to your Windows edition